# Why a hook value is not the same as event target value?

Tags: reactjs

I have an input and when its value changes, I log it, but when I type "John" in the input, the "e.target.value" = "John", and "searchInputValue" = "Joh",
It seems like "searchInputValue" always have the last letter missing,
How can I really get the e.target.value have the same value as searchInputValue ?

```
const [searchInputValue, setSearchInputValue] = useState("");

function handleChange(e) {
  setSearchInputValue(e.target.value);
  console.log("target value ", e.target.value); <- return the good value
  console.log("searchValue ", searchInputValue); <- return the value without 
  the last letter typed
}

<input
  type="text"
   onChange={e => handleChange(e)}
/>
```

Can someone help me ? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

`setSearchInputValue` is asynchronous and also you get the new state in the next render. That is the reason you won't see it right away.

Also, you need your input to be controlled.

```
<input
  type="text"
  value = {searchInputValue}
   onChange={e => handleChange(e)}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same problem when I was trying to use the React Hooks. The basic concept that you are missing here is that "setSearchInputValue" is an asynchronous function.

To get the updated value use "useEffect" hooks.

```
    useEffect(() => {
     console.log("searchValue ", searchInputValue);
  },[searchInputValue]);
```

Comment: You don;'t need to do that, the value is updated in the next render.

Comment: @paruchuri-p I know I need not to do that. I was just letting him know a way to get the updated value if he needs.